# How to get the value from this structure of an Object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

[image]

I wanted to display the value of `status` field from the `boardings` table which is in a relationship with `travel` table. When I do this code:

```
$travel->boardings->status
```

it returns an error that says, `$status` is undefined.

Comment: Because ```boardings``` is a collection in ```$travel```, you may access it using ```$travel->boardings[0]->status```, or iterate it like ```foreach($travel->boardings as $key=>$boarding){$status = $boarding->status}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see `boardings` is of type Collection so you can use it with index

```
$travel->boardings[0]->status
```

or by using for loop

```
 foreach($travel->boardings  as $boarding){
        $status = $boarding->status;
}
```